# Display image legend on hover (not as tooltip) using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, image, hover, innerhtml

I have a webpage with many images, each of which has a `title` attribute. When I hover over the image, I want the `title` text to display in a separate `legend` element I have created (*not as a tiny hover tooltip*).  I have a `mouseover` function which works fine - i.e. when I hover over the image the legend changes value. But I want that value to be the `title` text of the individual image - which I don't know how to access. I have tried `…innerHTML = this.title` which is obviously incorrect.

[The number of images is large and changing (like an album), so I can't add separate code for each `<img>` tag.  I can use `alt` or any other `<img>` attribute to make this work. I'm not wedded to the `innerHTML` method, either, but am hoping for some simple code to do the trick!]

Please help?  Thanks! (FYI, I'm a novice coder.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <h1 id="legend">title appears here</h1>

  <div>
    <img src="image1.jpg" onmouseover="mouseOver()" title="Breakfast">
    <img src="image2.jpg" onmouseover="mouseOver()" title="Lunch">
    <img src="image3.jpg" onmouseover="mouseOver()" title="Dinner">
  </div>

  <script>
    function mouseOver() {
        document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = this.title;
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to use `this.title` to represent the different images? If you want their titles to appear in the `<h1>` tag you need to pass the information to the function shown below.

```html
 <h1 id="legend">title appears here</h1>

  <div>
    <img src="image1.jpg" onmouseover="mouseOver(this)" title="Breakfast">
    <img src="image2.jpg" onmouseover="mouseOver(this)" title="Lunch">
    <img src="image3.jpg" onmouseover="mouseOver(this)" title="Dinner">
  </div>

  <script>
    function mouseOver(x) {
        document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = x.title;
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess its helpful .

> But i use **Jquery**
>   just need call this code in your `<head>`
>
> ```
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <h1 id="legend">title appears here</h1>

      <div>
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="class_of_div" title="Breakfast">
        <img src="image2.jpg" class="class_of_div" title="Lunch">
        <img src="image3.jpg" class="class_of_div" title="Dinner">
      </div>

      <script>
        $(document).on('mouseover', '.class_of_div', function () {
            var thiss=$(this);
            $('#legend').text(thiss.attr('title'));
        });
      </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```